# Installation of VLC Player fails with “E: Unable to fetch some archives”

Tags: apt, package-management, vlc

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgles2-mesa_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa-vdpau-drivers_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The installation of VLC fails with the above messages – what can I do?

Comment: Please try `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a` and provide the full output of each command by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/964332/edit) and using a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: If it solved your problem please accept my answer by clicking the tick on the left so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The following three commands often solve problems like that while doing no harm whatsoever:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a
```